# C Macros - Pass by Pointer vs Copy/Errors in passing to macro

Tags: c, gcc, vector, macros

In an effort to learn pure C (coming from C++), I've decided to write a simple math library using structs and macros.

So far, I have this as a test macro:

```
#define MulVec2(dest,src) ((dest.x) = (dest.x) * (src.x); (dest.y) = (dest.y) * (src.y); return dest;)

typedef struct vec2f_s
{
    float x, y;
}
vec2f_t;
```

In my calling code, I have this:

```
int main(void)
{

    vec2f_t v, w;

    v.x = 5.0f;
    v.y = 2.0f;

    w.x = 3.0f;
    w.y = 3.0f;

    v = MulVec2(v, w);

    printf( "x => %f; y => %f \n", v.x, v.y );

    return 0;
}
```

My questions are as follows:

1) Do I need to write a separate macro for passing pointers/addresses of objects to a macro? If so, how? For instance, note that the `MulVec2(dest,src)` macro assumes the objects passed in aren't dynamically allocated, but I'd like support for that as well.

2) When I compile the code, I get this error:

```
../main.c: In function 'main':
../main.c:15:9: error: expected ')' before ';' token
../main.c:15:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'vec2f_t' from type 'float'
```

What can I do to fix this?

**Edit**

I should have clarified that I don't plan to use *just* macros for this, but the reason for writing a macro is so I don't have to write a separate function for double and float variations of the vectors. I'd like it to be as reusable as possible by following the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle .

Comment: You want that in a function, not a macro.

Comment: Why are you doing that in a macro?

Comment: A function would definitely make things simpler. That said, you won't be able to make the same macro/function work for both the object and pointers since C doesn't support overloading.

Comment: Here's your problem: *"I've decided to write a simple math library using structs and macros"*. Just don't. Abusing the preprocessor is kinda fun, but it isn't good for you or anybody else. [I know of what I speak](http://dut.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: For this special case, the comma operator can be used: `#define MulVec2(dest,src) ((dest.x) = (dest.x) * (src.x), (dest.y) = (dest.y) * (src.y), (dest))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out, macros are not functions, and this would be a use case for a function. A macro simply textually expands Mul2Vec(...) to what you wrote in the macro, which fails to make any sense to the compiler, since one can't `return` out of an expression.

If you want to achieve the effect of C++ templates in C, reconsider your strategy, perhaps to simply choose one of `float` or `double` and stick to it. But if you absolutely must do generics without code duplication, you can define function-defining macros like this:

```
/* vec-impl.h */

#define PASTE(a, b) a ## b
#define NAME(prefix, type) PASTE(prefix, type)

#define VEC_T NAME(vec_, T)

typedef struct {
  T x;
  T y;
} VEC_T;

void NAME(MulVec2_, VEC_T)(VEC_T *dest, VEC_T *src) {
 dest->x = dest->x * src->x;
 dest->y = dest->y * src->y; 
}
```

Compilation units that define actual functions would look like this:

```
/* vec-double.c */

#define T double
#include "vec-impl.h"

/* vec-float.c */

#define T float    
#include "vec-impl.h"
```

This setup gives you a poor man's approximation of C++ templates, without type inference and any of the fancy metaprogramming features. Again, don't go that route unless you absolutely have to, and even then, minimize the code that does it. This is not idiomatic C code, and will not be well-received by competent C programmers—while C is more open to preprocessor hacking than C++, this is well over the line.

Regarding the code you posted: to get a feeling of what macros are, get a good book on C that explains the topic, such as Kernighan and Ritchie's "The C Programming language". When exploring macros, please keep in mind the following:

- Unless you really know what you are doing, never `return` out of a macro. If you do it anyway, make the word RETURN part of the macro name. The same goes for other flow-control statements, such as `break`, `continue`, and `goto`. People maintaining that code after you will appreciate it.
- By convention, macros are always spelled with all-caps, so it's MUL_VEC2, not MulVec2. This alerts the reader that he's dealing with a macro, not a function.
- The point of parentheses in macro definition is for the macro expansion to work even if passed a compound expression. Therefore it's `dest` that must be parenthesized, not `dest.x`. I.e. instead of `(dest.x)`, one would write `(dest).x`.
- Use the `-E` switch to the compiler to show you the preprocessor output, so you can see what the compiler sees and figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thank you, sir/ma'am. I edited my post to clarify a few things. Do you still think that a function should be used?

Comment: I've now updated the response to cover the clarified question.

Comment: Wow, this is an awesome answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Macros are not functions!

When you call `MulVec2(v, w)`, it simply replaces the macro with its defined value.

After the preprocessing the code will look like this:

```
int main(void)
{

    vec2f_t v, w;

    v.x = 5.0f;
    v.y = 2.0f;

    w.x = 3.0f;
    w.y = 3.0f;

 v=MulVec2(dest,src) ((dest.x) = (dest.x) * (src.x); (dest.y) = (dest.y) * (src.y); 
    return dest;)


    printf( "x => %f; y => %f \n", v.x, v.y );

    return 0;
}
```

That's the reason for the compilation errors.  Simply replace the #define of the `MulVec2` with a function.

Answer (score 1):

This is bad design. Macros that evaluate their arguments multiple times are very error prone since side effects of expressions that you pass as arguments can blow up your whole code. Use `inline` functions almost the same as you would use them in C++.

As a general rule, don't use macros for things that can be done with a function.

Now if you have such a function, create another one that receives the arguments through pointers, name it `MulVec2p`, say. Then with a new feature of C11, called type generic macros, you could do something similar to function overloading in C++

```
#define MULVEC2(X, Y)                \
(_Generic((X),                       \
  struct vec2f_s: MulVec2,           \
  struct vec2f_s*: MulVec2p)         \
   ((X), (Y)))
```

(this one only tests for the type of the first argument, but I hope you get the picture.)

C11 is not yet fully supported by compilers, but clang for example already has `_Generic`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a C99 compiler, this version of your macro will do what you want it to do:

```
  #define DOT2(a, b) ((vec2f_t){(a).x * (b).x, (a).y * (b).y})
```

By convention, but *especially* if they evaluate their arguments twice, as is the case here, macros MUST have an UGLY_NAME in upper-case. I love macros, but I know from bitter experience that if you don't follow this rule, you'll rue the day.  So I've replaced your `MulVec2` with `DOT2;` `MULVEC2` would also work.

Also by convention, the macro parameters are always enclosed in parentheses, for example `(a).x`. Cf. *rue*. Exceptions to this rule indicate to the reader that you are doing something unusual and/or wrong. But `fabs((a))` is probably unnecessary.

With this macro, you can even take the address (tested with gcc):

```
   extern void foo(vec2f_t *);
   // ...
   foo(&DOT2(ying, yang));
```

Answer (score 0):

for the second question - remove return desc; from macro, you can't assign this macro to anyone